# I have an alert showing something want to make it always shown

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a trained ml model that shows the ideal bedtime in an alert when you press the button "calculate" I want the ideal bedtime to always be shown on the top

can someone help?

```
import CoreML
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var wakeUp = defultWakeUpTime
    @State private var sleepAmount = 8.0
    @State private var coffeAmount = 1
    
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    static var defultWakeUpTime: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 0
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date.now
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section() {
                    
                    Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents:
                            .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                }
                Section() {
                    Text("Desigerd amount of sleep")
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    Stepper("\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12, step: 0.25)
                }
                Section() {
                    Text("Daily coffe intake")
                    Picker("Cups", selection: $coffeAmount) {
                        ForEach(1..<21) {
                            Text("\($0) Cups")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
//                    Stepper(coffeAmount == 1 ? "1 cup" : "\(coffeAmount) cups", value: $coffeAmount, in: 1...20)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Better Rest")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedTime)
            }
            .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Button("OK") { }
            } message: {
                Text(alertMessage)
            }
        }
    }
    func calculateBedTime() {
        do {
            let config = MLModelConfiguration()
            let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
            
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: wakeUp)
            let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
            let minute = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60
            
            let prediction = try model.prediction(wake: Double(hour + minute), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffee: Double(coffeAmount))
            
            let sleepTime = wakeUp - prediction.actualSleep
            alertTitle = "Your ideal bedtime is..."
            alertMessage = sleepTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
        } catch {
            alertTitle = "Error"
            alertMessage = "Sorry there was a problem calculating your bedtime."
        }
        
        showingAlert = true
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "always shown on top"? Alert blocks UI, so if it is always shown nothing else will work. Needed more details.

Comment: Maybe provide some kind of image or sketch

Comment: something like the answer at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to show the result as part of the main view.
For that you  need a new @State var to display the result when calculated, and add a new section to show it.
After the ML calculation the state var gets updated with the result and displays it. The Alert now only shows when an error occurred.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var wakeUp = defultWakeUpTime
    @State private var sleepAmount = 8.0
    @State private var coffeAmount = 1
    
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    // new State var to display result
    @State private var sleepTime = Date.now
    
    static var defultWakeUpTime: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 0
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date.now
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // new, display result
                Section() {
                    Text("Your ideal bedtime is...")
                        .bold()
                    Text(sleepTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))
                        .bold().foregroundColor(.green)
                }

                Section() {
                    Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                        .font(.headline)
                    DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents:
                            .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                }
                Section() {
                    Text("Desired amount of sleep")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Stepper("\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12, step: 0.25)
                }
                
                Section() {
                    Text("Daily coffe intake")
                    Picker("Cups", selection: $coffeAmount) {
                        ForEach(1..<21) {
                            Text("\($0) Cups")
                        }
                    }
//                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Better Rest")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedTime)
            }
            .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Button("OK") { }
            } message: {
                Text(alertMessage)
            }
        }
    }
    func calculateBedTime() {
        do {

            // your prediction calculations
            // ...
            
            // assign result to state var
            self.sleepTime = wakeUp - prediction.actualSleep
            
        } catch {
            alertTitle = "Error"
            alertMessage = "Sorry there was a problem calculating your bedtime."
            showingAlert = true // only show Alret on error
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it is great and all work but

"cannot find prediction in scope"

*in the function

Comment: at the place of the comment "// your prediction calculations ..." you should add the prediction code you already had in your example.